# block ALL keyboard access, mouse access and keyboard shortcut events

Tags: cocoa, events, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

In order to block ALL keyboard access, mouse access and keyboard shortcut events in one of my projects, I:

1. Created a full screen transparent borderless window, in front of other windows, but invisible.
2. Handle all keyboard and mouse events with simple `return;` the window itself.
3. Make the `window` modal `[NSApp runModalForWindow:myWindow]` in order to block keyboard shortcuts.
4. Release `window` from touchpad's gesture events only.

But this guy made it look simple in a tiny app -[MACIFIER](http://macifier.com/):

How did he do it?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049217/cgeventtap-blocks-application-input

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [Quartz Event Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html). In particular, have a look at [CGEventTapCreate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventTapCreate), and note the 4th parameter, which allows you to specify what kinds of events you'd like to intercept. The available kinds of events are listed in the [CGEventType](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGEventType) enum.

If you set your tap to be an active filter, returning `NULL` from the callback will delete the event.

Comment: do you mean block all events except gesture? any code in detail?

Comment: I've edited my answer; you can intercept all key-down, key-up, mouse movements, and so on. I think gestures is a more high-level mouse event, but that's ok - if you intercept all mouse movements, you also intercept gestures.

Comment: Where were you lost? I believe the documentation is quite easy to follow.

Comment: As the documentation says, your program must either be run as root, or the access for assistive devices be enabled. There's also a method called `CGEventTapCreateForPSN` which does the same for a specific process, and does not require root privileges.

Comment: found sample code here, but too hard to me. http://keymagic.googlecode.com/svn-history/r117/trunk/OSX/EventHandler.m

Answer (score 0):

not really sure if this would be usable, but you could use the program hotkeynet (generally used for gaming, but I have had success using other methods) and map every single key/mouse action to do nothing. I did something similar by blocking access to a specific program with it in about 20-30 minutes.

not sure if it will help; but it might be the solution you need?

Comment: I've already did it in my solution full screen solution but I am sure there should be a better one.

Comment: I am sure the app "MACIFIER" used a very simple way, better than mine at least.