# Mouse Events "Click Through Filter"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a transparent overlay placed on the desktop. 
Now I need only to catch the double-click events on my desktop-overlay layer, and "pass on" or simulate left-click and right-click to the below desktop.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [this answer abour intercepting events in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11476219/1071136). You can establish a tap, intercept clicks, and based on timing the clicks decide whether to pass them on or not.